# Is it possible to get averages from multiple rows in Excel?

Tags: algorithm, excel, math

How is it possible to produce averages of multiple data in excel?

If I have something like the following:

[image]

How would I calculate the average for each row of the table without programming each area under "AvgBest" and "AvgMean"? If it makes it any easier I'm happy to compute the best and mean in separate spread sheets as it can all be put back together afterwards.

I'm trying to produce the averages of all of the sample data.

Is this possible in Excel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To calculate the simple means, you could do the following. For the average best:

```
  =AVERAGE(A2,D2,G2,J2)
```

in cell M2, and then copied down to the end of your data.

For the average mean:

```
  =AVERAGE(B2,E2,H2,K2)
```

in cell N2, and then copied down to the end of your data.

Comment: So I have to manually type in: M2 =AVERAGE(A2,D2,G2,J2), then for M3 = =AVERAGE(A3,D3,G3,J3) etc? I have 1000's of rows I need to get averages for hence I don't want to have to do it row by row.

Comment: What you should do is type it in for the first row, then copy that formula downward for all the rows. The references to the cells will automatically adjust to each new row. Shortcut way to do the copy: Select (highlight with your cursor) the two averages cells, press the Control-C key combination, then highlight the cells you want to copy into and press the Control-V key combination.

Comment: If you put chuff's first formula in M2 you can apply that to a whole range - type the whole range in the box above A1, e.g. M2:M1000 - that selects the whole range - now hit CTRL+D to fill the whole range - the row numbers will adjust automatically